# Wait until even occurs and continue after it's processed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events

I am remotely controling external camera. I can take picture by asynchronously calling `TakePhotoAsync()` method, and when picture is taken and ready for download, event `DownloadReady` occurs which contains DownloadInfo about taken picture. I have method `Cam_DownloadReady(...)` to process this event. 
This is given by API, I can't change anything.

But I need to take picture synchronously. Something like call `TakePhotoAsync()` and wait at this line until event `DownloadReady` occurs, which calls `Cam_DownloadReady(...)`method, and after this method is executed and finished, then `// continue..` (as marked in code section). Is this possible? Thank you

```
public Task<CameraImage> GetImageFromCameraAsync(string cameraId) 
{
    APIHandler = new CanonAPI();
    Camera MainCamera = APIHandler.GetCameraList()[0];
    MainCamera.DownloadReady += Cam_DownloadReady;
    MainCamera.OpenSession();
    MainCamera.TakePhotoAsync();
    // wait here until event occurs and is processed
    // Cam_DownloadReady(...) is called and finished
    // continue ...
}

private void Cam_DownloadReady(Camera sender, DownloadInfo Info)
{
    sender.DownloadFile(Info, saveImageDir); //save picture on PC
}
```

Comment: You can use `async/await` pattern or use `ContinueWith`

Comment: You're not awaiting 'MainCamera.TakePhotoAsync();' try 'await MainCamera.TakePhotoAsync();'.

Comment: method is declared in library .dll as `public void TakePhotoAsync()`, so I can't use `async/await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
using System.Threading;     
public ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false); // created in the unsignaled state.

    public Task<CameraImage> GetImageFromCameraAsync(string cameraId)
    {
        mre.Reset(); // Set the state of the event to be nonsignaled 
        APIHandler = new CanonAPI();
        Camera MainCamera = APIHandler.GetCameraList()[0];
        MainCamera.DownloadReady += Cam_DownloadReady;
        MainCamera.OpenSession();
        MainCamera.TakePhotoAsync();
        // wait here until event occurs and is processed
        mre.WaitOne(); // Block the current thread until the current wait handle receives a signal
        // Cam_DownloadReady(...) is called and finished
        // continue ...
    }

    private void Cam_DownloadReady(Camera sender, DownloadInfo Info)
    {
        sender.DownloadFile(Info, saveImageDir); //save picture on PC
        mre.Set(); // Set the state of the event to signaled, allowing mre.WaitOne() above to proceed.
    }
```

Comment: this works, thank you very much, you really helped me